# DatePicker doesn't work for Dialog in Partial view using asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have 'jquery-1.12.4.js', 'jquery-ui-1.12.0.js' and my css in my shared layout.

I'm using jquery dialog to popup.

and I call my partial view and load it.

```
$element.dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    width: wSize,
    height: hSize,
    resizable: true,
    draggable: true,
    title: dTitle,
    closeOnEscape: true,
    open: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).load(url);
    },

    close: function () {
        $(this).css("display", "none"); 
    }
});


$("#elementID").dialog("open");
```

In my server side..

```
public ActionResult stats(string sDate, string eDate, string Mode, int Id)
    {
        ...

        try
        {
            ...
            Model stats = GetDatabase

            ViewData["StartDate"] = sDate;
            ViewData["EndDate"] = eDate;

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ...
        }

        return View(stats);   
    }
```

In my partial view.. (no refer jquery, jquery-ui script)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#txtStartDate').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        prevText: ..,
        nextText: ..,
        monthNames: ..,
        monthNamesShort: ..,
        dayNames: ...
        dayNamesShort: ...,
        dayNamesMin: ...,
        showMonthAfterYear: ..,
        yearSuffix: ..
    });
});
```

```
<input type="text" id="txtStartDate" value="@startDate" class="form-control" />
```

In that case, I can see hasDatePicker class in developer tool but calendar doesn't appear and It's nothing inside.
Even more, I can't see any error message in my console.

In chrome developer tool ...

```
<div id="ui-datepicker-div" class="ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all"></div>
```

My main page, I have exactly same datepicker but it works fine.

In chrome developer tool...

```
<input type="text" id="current_date1" name="current_date1" class="form-control date-picker hasDatepicker">
```

[datepicker in main view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYbpt.png)

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation to this and it only worked when I added the datepicker function after my partial view is rendered and not in the shared layout.

So in your case would be after opening the dialog